# Task :app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, yarnpkg, building

When i try to run
`cd android` 
`./gradlew assemleRelease`

**This is terminal output**

> Task :app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets
> warning: the transform cache was reset.
> Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
> Fast - Scalable - Integrated

info Writing bundle output to:, C:\Users\CABBAR\Documents\github repo\TarifistClient\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\dev\release\index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\Users\CABBAR\Documents\github repo\TarifistClient\android\app\build\intermediates\sourcemaps\react\dev\release\index.android.bundle.packager.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 286 asset files
info Done copying assets
'C:\Users\CABBAR\Documents\github' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> Task :app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\CABBAR\Documents\github repo\TarifistClient\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 286
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BU¦LD FAILED in 1m 29s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
PS C:\Users\CABBAR\Documents\github repo\TarifistClient\android>

```
i have tried :
`cd android` `./gradlew --stop` `./gradlew clean` and
also deleted node_modules and loaded again with `yarn install`
after that when i run `cd android `
`./gradlew assemleRelease` it still same problem.

// also i tried this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` but terminal gibing this error:
```

react-native: The term 'react-native' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i want to get a build without this error 'Task :app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED'.
i am running this code on root project.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

after delete last builds (for any crash):// Daha önce alınan buildleri temizler - Clears previous builds

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

we have a 2 build types in android > build.gradle file
so i can get a build in two types also my error is caused by that.
So when i want to get a build on Develop i need to run this command on `root > android`

```
                **DEVELOP**
```

//apk build’i için - for apk build

```
./gradlew assembleDevRelease -x bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets
```

//aab build’i için - for abb build

```
./gradlew bundleDevRelease -x bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets
```

```
                **PRODUCTION**
```

//apk build’i için - for apk build

```
./gradlew assembleProdRelease -x bundleProdReleaseJsAndAssets
```

//aab build’i için - for abb build

```
./gradlew bundleProdRelease -x bundleProdReleaseJsAndAssets
```

and just wait without erRor i hope. D:

After build you can discard new created files.